# Cannot login in laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to authenticate a user through Ajax in Laravel.

```
public function authenticate(){
        $email = Input::get('email');
        $password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));

        if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
            return Response::json(["success"=>"true", "login"=>"false", "error_msg"=>"<span style='margin-bottom:20px;' class='val_error_msg'>Email is not valid!</span>"]);
        }
        elseif(Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])){
            return Response::json(["success"=>"true", "login"=>"false", "error_msg"=>"<span style='margin-bottom:20px;' class='val_error_msg'>Logged in</span>"]);
        }
        else{
            return Response::json(["success"=>"true", "login"=>"false", "error_msg"=>"<span style='margin-bottom:20px;' class='val_error_msg'>Email/password is wrong</span>"]);
        }
    }
```

Ajax call

```
    $.post(
             '/login/authenticate', // location of your php script
             { email: $("#log_email").val(), password: $("#log_password").val()}, // any data you want to send to the script
                            function( data ){  // a function to deal with the returned information
              if(data.login=='false'){
                    $("#login_response").empty();
                    $("#login_response").append(data.error_msg);
              }
 });
```

But I'm getting the `Email/password is wrong` message all the time even if the credentials are good.

I tried `if((User::where('email', $email)->where('pasword', $password)->count())==1)` and it worked.

What's wrong in the `Auth::attempt()` method?

Comment: First try without hasing your password @user1012181

Comment: Are you hashing the password when you save the user to the db?

Comment: Yes I'm .. I'm saving it like `md5(password)`. Should I be worried for not using `Hash::make(password)` ?

Comment: @user1012181 YES. You have to use `Hash::make($password)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass the password in plain text to `Auth::attempt()`:

```
$password = Input::get('password');
Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])
```

### Edit

Apparently you are using md5 to hash your password. This is not only insecure but will also not work with Laravel's Auth methods. Use `Hash::make()` instead when creating the user instead:

```
$user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
```

Comment: Is your database field for the password hash at least 60 characters long?

Comment: Whats the diff between `md5()` and `Hash::make` ?

Comment: [`Hash::make()`](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security) uses bcrypt hashing, which is accepted as a more secure method of hashing a string.

Comment: `Hash::make` also incorporates a random salt which makes every hash look different even if its the same password. Besides that, md5 without a salt is the most insecure thing ever. Common passwords can easily be cracked using lookup tables (called rainbow tables) because the hash for the same password always looks the same.

Answer (score 1):

Three things:

When you attempt to log in, you need to pass in the password pre-hashed

```
$password = Input::get('password');
```

Secondly, your return JSON appears to be setting login to false on a valid login attempt. Change it to true:

```
return Response::json(["success" => 'true', "login" => 'true', "error_msg" => "<span style='margin-bottom:20px;' class='val_error_msg'>Logged in</span>"]);
```

Thirdly, when you store the user into your database, you must use `Hash::make('string')` to build their password.

Comment: Don't worry about the false value. I just wanted to see the msg on the view. I tried first one and didn't work.

Comment: @user1012181 Edited. MD5'ing the password is not good practice. Fix your registration/insertion method to use Hash::make instead of md5, then re-try logging in.